# Images from json does not appear

Tags: reactjs, json

I have a problem on my project where everything from the json file works on the site except images, i can't make images to show on the site and i don't know what to do.

I'm looking at the code and everything seems right...i'm sure i did something wrong but i can't figure out what

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
 import data from "../data.json";
    
    const Destination = () => {
      const [planets] = useState(data.destinations);
      const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    
      const { name, images, description, distance, travel } = planets[value];
    
      return (
        <div className="h-screen p-6 font-main bg-dest-m bg-no-repeat bg-cover text-white lg:flex lg:bg-dest-d ">
          <div className="text-center lg:w-1/2 lg:flex lg:flex-col lg:justify-center">
            <h1 className="lg:text-3xl tracking-widest md:text-2xl md:pt-10">
              01 PICK YOUR DESTINATION
            </h1>
            <img src={images.png} alt={name} className="h-48" />
          </div>
          <div className="lg:w-1/2  lg:px-24 lg:flex lg:flex-col lg:justify-center md:px-24">
            <div className="flex justify-around items-center px-8 my-10 text-gray-400 lg:w-3/4 lg:px-0 md:px-40">
              {planets.map((planet, index) => {
                return (
                  <button key={index} onClick={() => setValue(index)}>
                    {planet.name}
                  </button>
                );
              })}
            </div>
            <h1 className="text-center my-5 text-6xl lg:text-left">{name}</h1>
            <p className="text-center my-4 lg:text-left text-gray-400">
              {description}
            </p>
            <div className="w-full bg-gray-500 h-px my-8"></div>
            <div className="lg:flex lg:justify-between lg:items-center lg:w-2/3 lg:mt-8 ">
              <div className="text-center text-lg lg:text-left">
                <p className="text-sm text-gray-400">AVG. DISTANCE</p>
                <p className="text-2xl">{distance}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="text-center mt-6 text-lg lg:text-left lg:mt-0 ">
                <p className="text-sm text-gray-400">AVG. TRAVEL</p>
                <p className="text-2xl">{travel}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Destination;
```

JSON File

This is the json file in case it helps

```
{
  "destinations": [
    {
      "name": "Moon",
      "images": {
        "png": "./assets/destination/image-moon.png",
        "webp": "./assets/destination/image-moon.webp"
      },
      "description": "See our planet as you’ve never seen it before. A perfect relaxing trip away to help regain perspective and come back refreshed. While you’re there, take in some history by visiting the Luna 2 and Apollo 11 landing sites.",
      "distance": "384,400 km",
      "travel": "3 days"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mars",
      "images": {
        "png": "./assets/destination/image-mars.png",
        "webp": "./assets/destination/image-mars.webp"
      },
      "description": "Don’t forget to pack your hiking boots. You’ll need them to tackle Olympus Mons, the tallest planetary mountain in our solar system. It’s two and a half times the size of Everest!",
      "distance": "225 mil. km",
      "travel": "9 months"
    },
    {
      "name": "Europa",
      "images": {
        "png": "./assets/destination/image-europa.png",
        "webp": "./assets/destination/image-europa.webp"
      },
      "description": "The smallest of the four Galilean moons orbiting Jupiter, Europa is a winter lover’s dream. With an icy surface, it’s perfect for a bit of ice skating, curling, hockey, or simple relaxation in your snug wintery cabin.",
      "distance": "628 mil. km",
      "travel": "3 years"
    },
    {
      "name": "Titan",
      "images": {
        "png": "./assets/destination/image-titan.png",
        "webp": "./assets/destination/image-titan.webp"
      },
      "description": "The only moon known to have a dense atmosphere other than Earth, Titan is a home away from home (just a few hundred degrees colder!). As a bonus, you get striking views of the Rings of Saturn.",
      "distance": "1.6 bil. km",
      "travel": "7 years"
    }
  ],
  "crew": [
    {
      "name": "Douglas Hurley",
      "images": {
        "png": "./assets/crew/image-douglas-hurley.png",
        "webp": "./assets/crew/image-douglas-hurley.webp"
      },
      "role": "Commander",
      "bio": "Douglas Gerald Hurley is an American engineer, former Marine Corps pilot and former NASA astronaut. He launched into space for the third time as commander of Crew Dragon Demo-2."
    },
    {
      "name": "Mark Shuttleworth",
      "images": {
        "png": "./assets/crew/image-mark-shuttleworth.png",
        "webp": "./assets/crew/image-mark-shuttleworth.webp"
      },
      "role": "Mission Specialist",
      "bio": "Mark Richard Shuttleworth is the founder and CEO of Canonical, the company behind the Linux-based Ubuntu operating system. Shuttleworth became the first South African to travel to space as a space tourist."
    },
    {
      "name": "Victor Glover",
      "images": {
        "png": "./assets/crew/image-victor-glover.png",
        "webp": "./assets/crew/image-victor-glover.webp"
      },
      "role": "Pilot",
      "bio": "Pilot on the first operational flight of the SpaceX Crew Dragon to the International Space Station. Glover is a commander in the U.S. Navy where he pilots an F/A-18.He was a crew member of Expedition 64, and served as a station systems flight engineer."
    },
    {
      "name": "Anousheh Ansari",
      "images": {
        "png": "./assets/crew/image-anousheh-ansari.png",
        "webp": "./assets/crew/image-anousheh-ansari.webp"
      },
      "role": "Flight Engineer",
      "bio": "Anousheh Ansari is an Iranian American engineer and co-founder of Prodea Systems. Ansari was the fourth self-funded space tourist, the first self-funded woman to fly to the ISS, and the first Iranian in space."
    }
  ],
  "technology": [
    {
      "name": "Launch vehicle",
      "images": {
        "portrait": "./assets/technology/image-launch-vehicle-portrait.jpg",
        "landscape": "./assets/technology/image-launch-vehicle-landscape.jpg"
      },
      "description": "A launch vehicle or carrier rocket is a rocket-propelled vehicle used to carry a payload from Earth's surface to space, usually to Earth orbit or beyond. Our WEB-X carrier rocket is the most powerful in operation. Standing 150 metres tall, it's quite an awe-inspiring sight on the launch pad!"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spaceport",
      "images": {
        "portrait": "./assets/technology/image-spaceport-portrait.jpg",
        "landscape": "./assets/technology/image-spaceport-landscape.jpg"
      },
      "description": "A spaceport or cosmodrome is a site for launching (or receiving) spacecraft, by analogy to the seaport for ships or airport for aircraft. Based in the famous Cape Canaveral, our spaceport is ideally situated to take advantage of the Earth’s rotation for launch."
    },
    {
      "name": "Space capsule",
      "images": {
        "portrait": "./assets/technology/image-space-capsule-portrait.jpg",
        "landscape": "./assets/technology/image-space-capsule-landscape.jpg"
      },
      "description": "A space capsule is an often-crewed spacecraft that uses a blunt-body reentry capsule to reenter the Earth's atmosphere without wings. Our capsule is where you'll spend your time during the flight. It includes a space gym, cinema, and plenty of other activities to keep you entertained."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of `images` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Current code will look into /public folder to find your images. You should move your assets to /public instead of /src (manually or by bundle tool) to make it work properly

**OR ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**
As an option you can save your data in js format, and then use require export

```
const data = [
    {
        "name": "Mars",
        "image": require("../public/images/test.jpg")
    },
    {
        "name": "Europa",
        "images": {
            "png": require("./assets/destination/image-mars.png"),
            "webp": require("./assets/destination/image-mars.webp")
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: After i got this problem i searched on youtube for people that had done the same challange and a lot of them are doing it the same way like i'm doing it, so i don't understand why for me does not work.And i done the same thing in other projects without changing the json file into a js file

Comment: @Em1n3m you're right, there is other solution that i have updated, so moving images into public folder instead of src will make it work